# r data.table - conditionally writing to external file

Tags: r, data.table

Is it possible to write conditionally to an external file from data.table ? Currently using basic for loop and then access row/columns but it is very slow.

```
for (row in seq_len(nrow(dt))) {    

   <if - else condition by accessing row and column as dt[row, column]>

    write(<text>, file=<file>, append=append)
}
```

There are very complex conditions and not easy to convert and then use fwrite to dump output from data.table into an external file (assuming that is the fastest option)

I am just wondering if data.table support "set" will be faster (example from one of blog as below) than basic for loop but then how can we execute fwrite() from data.table's "set" ?

```
dt <- data.table(mtcars)[,1:5, with=F]
for (j in c(1L,2L,4L)) set(dt, j=j, value=-dt[[j]]) # integers using 'L' passed for efficiency
for (j in c(3L,5L)) set(dt, j=j, value=paste0(dt[[j]],'!!'))
head(dt)
```

Comment: Frankly, I suspect that doing this row-by-row is about as inefficient (from R-efficiencies) as feasible. I suggest doing your `if` in one step and writing the resulting rows in one step. I also don't see how your first block (iterate over rows, write one row at a time) relates to your second block (iterate over columns, `set` to update each column appropriately). How do the two relate? Ultimately, what is your required operation on `dt` and `<file>`?

Comment: @r2evans code shown in two blocks are just for reference and I agree one is by row and the other is by column. I am more looking solution by row. I am not exploring the option to process everything in data.table and then dump output using fwrite().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just need to block the code in `{}` i.e. after we apply the `set`, the original dataset 'dt' is updated.  Then, we use `fwrite` on the transformed dataset with a new file name

```
library(data.table)
for(i in seq_len(nrow(dt))) {
  for (j in c(1L,2L,4L)) {
     set(dt, i = i, j=j, value=-dt[[j]][i])
     fwrite(dt, 'yourfile.csv', append = TRUE)
}
}
```

Comment: THanks, My situation is getting control at row level and then conditionally process and then write the content of that row to CSV file. i.e. processing one row at a time

Comment: @R007 Where do you want the `fwrite` to be wrritten.  Is it just a single file after all the processing?  Then, you can do the `fwrite` outside the loop.  Your code ` `write(<text>, file=<file>, append=append` shows it is written within the loop

Comment: yes single file. I usue write() with append=TRUE

Comment: @R007 then, just change the file name as in the update i.e. a single file name and use `append = TRUE` (which is also there in `fwrite`

Comment: @R007 If you are looping over the rows, then `i` is not specified

Comment: in my current code (using basic for-loop), I am using "row" variable for i

Comment: @R007 in your data.table, code, you are just looping over the columns with `j` and specifying only 'j' part in `set`

Comment: @R007 i updated the post with `i` as well.  Not clear what you wanted

Comment: Sorry for confusin, 1st section of code (for-loop with nrow()...that is what I am using now and 2nd section of code ("set") is something I took it from blog so discussion. I dont know how to make it work using "set"

Comment: @R007 REgarding whether this is faster or not, you could check with `microbenchmark` or `benchmark` packages

Comment: @R007 I updated the post.  Can you check the code now